# In repositories, does software under the LGPL include a copy of the GPL?

Tags: gpl, gpl-3, lgpl, github

The repository for something that I need to use has 2 license txt. One which is the LGPL and the other the GPLv3. I heard from a member of their Discord that this is because the LGPL is an extension to the GPL, so a copy of the GPL is always in the repository of a LGPL product.

Both txt have a description that reads "We're LGPL" though.

Answer (score 5):

The LGPL Version 3 uses the GPL-3.0 Additional Permissions mechanism to add a linking exception to the GPL. The LGPL-3.0 is not a standalone license, but rather a standardized GPL exception. Therefore, yes, any project under the LGPL-3.0 must include the GPL license text as well.

However, earlier LGPL versions are standalone licenses and only require a copy of the LGPL to be provided, not a copy of the GPL.